# Which SharePoint versions support CMIS?

Tags: cmis

Some recent versions of SharePoint can be accessed via the CMIS protocol.

Which versions natively support CMIS?

Which versions support CMIS by installing an official Microsoft addon?

Comment: Don't know for SP 2013, but the SP 2010 version is very unreliable, and works only with EN setup (at least without cheating).

Comment: @SteveB: EN=English? Do you have any reference for this? I am expected to install in Japanese if there is no solid reason not to.

Comment: Actually, I tried to make this work on an English platform, with the French Language Pack. However, the setup only created ressources for the EN-US culture. I add to manually duplicate the resources files for the FR-fr culture to avoid log flooding and some errors. And for your information, we totally abandonned this tool because it was very unreliable, especially with our custom claims authentication provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- SharePoint Server 2016: **YES**
- SharePoint 2013 Foundation: **NO**
- SharePoint Server 2013: **YES** [disabled by default](http://dhartford.blogspot.jp/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-w-apache-chemistry-cmis.html)
- SharePoint 2010 Foundation: **NO**
- SharePoint Server 2010: **YES** [via extension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934619%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- SharePoint 2007 Foundation: **NO**
- SharePoint Server 2007: **YES** [via extension](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20022)

By the way, if you are interested in CMIS support for SharePoint Online (Office365), please [ask Microsoft to implement it](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19504168-allow-cmis-access-to-sharepoint).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this support started with SharePoint 2010 by Microsoft bringing out the CMIS Connector, however this is an additional install. However it is available in SharePoint 2013, out of the box.

There is a good post on StackOverflow which is related to SharePoint 2010: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090255/cmis-and-sharepoint

SharePoint 2010 Administration Toolkit Information here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508851(v=office.14).aspx

SharePoint 2013 Information here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163233.aspx

Comment: When asking I was also thinking about the Foundation version, do you have any info about that one?

Comment: Looking at the information for SharePoint 2013 it is related to SharePoint 2013 Server rather than Foundation.

Comment: The connector is for SharePoint 2010 Server, not Foundation.