# Third-party add-on to enable CMIS on SharePoint Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, cmis

Some of my clients use SharePoint Foundation.

My software relies on CMIS, which is [not supported for Foundation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58947/which-sharepoint-versions-support-cmis).

Is there any third-party extension they could install to make their SharePoint accessible via CMIS?

Preferably free, Open Source would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have found CMIS4SharePoint:

http://cmis4sharepoint.codeplex.com

It is Open Source.

> It’s an implementation in accordance with the draft version 0.5 of the standard. It covers the webservice part and aims to be a complete implementation of CMIS.
>   WSS3.0 & MOSS2007

The project does not seem to be maintained unfortunately.

Another option is to [pressure Microsoft into enabling CMIS in Foundation](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6003155-implement-cmis-for-real).